# How to set preview size of camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to set a preview and picture sizes as parameters to the camera as shown in the code below. I also added some log statement to accertain that the sizes set properly. the problem is i got different sizes in the logcat as 
shown in logcat output section below.

please let me know how to set preview and picture sizes properly.

**code**:

```
        mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(400,400);
        parameters.setPictureSize(400, 400);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        mPreviewWidth = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
        mPreviewHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
        Log.d(TAG, "parameters mPreviewWidth: " + mPreviewWidth);
        Log.d(TAG, "parameters mPreviewHeight: " + mPreviewHeight);
```

**logcat output**:

```
11-14 15:17:58.207 20492-20492/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: parameters mPreviewWidth: 960
11-14 15:17:58.207 20492-20492/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: parameters mPreviewHeight: 720
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all sizeq and try to minimize the difference of area between theses sizes and your preview size.

you can check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L511-L518)

Comment: If your preview size is not supported by the camera, it will not work